# How to detect memory leakage in spring boot

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, java-17

In my spring boot application RAM usage is growing day by day. After restarting the application RAM usage become normal. Spring boot version 2.7.5, Data JPA, MySQL, Java 17.

I'm already check my code with via peer review and it was perfect. Hope will overcome this issue.

Comment: you can use java virtualvm,it usually located in bin directory of your jdk directory.it will show you your threads and memory and who using them

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and two hours later another SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  by comparing the TWO reports, we will likely find someone likely has not followed the CONNECT, PROCESS, CLOSE and the result is processes hanging around because the close has not been consistently used to release resources.